# My jquery/ajax website not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, yahoo-api

I have a script which allows to display cross domain data, example: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4QCt/113/)

I have put the exact same code on my website [moskah.nl](http://moskah.nl/) as you can see I get a blank page. How is this possible ?????? Do you think my website provider is somehow blocking/restricting the code?? Is it the ajax call to "//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?" , that maybe is not working in the Netherlands ?? I have talked to the helpdesk of my provider but they don't know (anything!) what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting js error, which you can see in firebug console and you are getting jquery is not defined error. try loading jquery like this(added type attribute),

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scripts.embed.ly/jquery.embedly.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try laoding the official jquery from google cdn...lets chcek if that works

Comment: HAHAHAHAAAHAHHHHAAA (Im so embarrassed right now...) Thank you very much:) I knew I should have had that cup of coffee first..